# Using input$ to call the dataset

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Suppose I have 2 columns in my dataset, and I want to output out a histogram and summary depending on which column we are on, currently I have 2 if statements per output checking what the input is equal to.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("First iteration"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("Sidebar Panel",
    selectInput("typetoshow", "Choose what you want to display", 
                choices = c("pts", "upts"))             
                 ),
    mainPanel("main panel",
              plotOutput("hist"),
              verbatimTextOutput("sum")
              )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    if (input$typetoshow == "pts"){
      hist(data$pts)
    }
    if (input$typetoshow == "upts"){
      hist(data$upts)
    }
  })
  output$sum <- renderPrint({
    if (input$typetoshow == "pts"){
      summary(data$pts)
    }
    if (input$typetoshow == "upts"){
     summary(data$upts)
    }
  })
}
```

I tried doing

```
hist(data$input$typetoshow)
```

But it is giving me an error saying 'x must be numeric' in the histogram and shows NULL for the output summary, is there any way to do this without making many if statements? I am going to be dealing with 10+ columns at one point so I want the code to be neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `req` at the top and then use `[[` to subset the dataset column based on the value from 'input$typetoshow'

```
server <- function(input, output){
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    req(input$typetoshow)
    
    
      hist(data[[input$typetoshow]])
   
  })
  output$sum <- renderPrint({
       req(input$typetoshow)
    
      summary(data[[input$typetoshow]])
    
  })
```

Comment: Sorry I don't see how this simplifies anything? The number of if statements remains the same?

Comment: @Wallace I read your question as `But it is giving me an error saying 'x must be numeric' in the histogram and shows NULL`

Comment: Ah, no the general block of code I sent you works fine, it's just I am trying to remove the need for all the if statements, so rather than check what the value is equal to, I want to just plot the input type

Comment: @Wallace the issue is that I saw an error in the description and I thought it is what you want to rectify

Comment: The error occurs when I attempt ```hist(data$input$typetoshow)```, not when there are if statements, sorry for being unclear

Comment: @Wallace updaed the post

Comment: Wow, this worked and was exactly what I wanted, thank you so much. You already solved my problem but if you have extra time do you mind explaining to me what the double square brackets do in R? I primarily work with Python

Comment: @Wallace It is just that `$` match literally and your code is correct with `if/else` when you are using `$`, but `[[` is more general as it can evaluate the object to get the value inside i.e. from `input$typetoshow`, with `$`, it will be read as literally

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler with `dplyr::select`:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(unlist(dplyr::select(data, input$typetoshow)))
  })
  output$sum <- renderPrint({
    summary(dplyr::select(data, input$typetoshow))

    })
}
```

Comment: Ooh, never considered this route, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: you're welcome :) if you could vote my answer as positive would be great! Cheers